# multi-level html menu controlled by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm facing an issue with a multi level menu. I need jQuery to show or hide the current selected submenu, and keep the others with no changes. I'm not very skillful with JQuery yet, so any help would be highly appreciated. I'm sharing here with you what I have. Thanks in advance!

I'd like to mention that I found an example on StackOverflow that is partially working. After some debugging I realized that the `var mobileMenu.css` returns `undefined` and that makes the code sometimes works.

```js
var test1 = $('ul.hdrMenu li');

test1.on( 'click', function(e) 
{   
    var mobileMenuItem  = $(e.target).parent().find( '> ul.sub-menu' );

    if( **typeof mobileMenuItem.css('display') === "undefined"** )
    {
        mobileMenuItem  = $(e.target).parent().parent().find( '> ul.sub-menu' );          
    }

    if( mobileMenuItem.css('display') == 'none' ) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        mobileMenuItem.slideDown();
        e.stopPropagation();
    } 
    else if( mobileMenuItem.css('display') == 'block' ) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        mobileMenuItem.slideUp();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hdrMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Servicios</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">L2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">L2-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">L2-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">L3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">L4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">L4-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">L4-4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Acerca de</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no `.hdrNav` element in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code work just fine I think you need just to remove the parent selector `.hdrNav` it must be like :

```
var test1 = $('ul.hdrMenu li');
```

Or you can leave the selector as it's and add a parent div with the class `hdrNav`.

```js
var test1 = $('ul.hdrMenu li');
test1.on('click', function(e) {
  var mobileMenu = $(e.target).parent().find('> ul.sub-menu');

  if (mobileMenu.css('display') == 'none') {
    e.preventDefault();
    mobileMenu.slideDown();
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else if (mobileMenu.css('display') == 'block') {
    e.preventDefault();
    mobileMenu.slideUp();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hdrMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Servicios</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">L2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">L2-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">L2-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">L3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">L4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">L4-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">L4-4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Acerca de</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are right, this code is working fine.... I appreciate the time you spent taking a look at it. 

The real code I was debugging includes an arrow icon. so when I clicked the arrow instead of the label itself, the code wasn't able to find the right parent to hide/show the submenu. This is the final jQuery code.  Thanks again a lot for your feeedback.